# In `lazysizes.js` what do the width values in datasets actually do?

Tags: javascript, html, lazy-loading, lazysizes

I'm using the JS plugin Lazysizes.js https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes

I'm using multiple images in `data-srcset`, but I'm confused as to what the trailing widths do, eg:

```
<img
    data-sizes="auto"
    data-src="image3.jpg"
    data-srcset="image3.jpg 600w,
        image1.jpg 220w,
        image2.jpg 300w,
        image3.jpg 600w,
        image4.jpg 900w"
    class="lazyload" />
```

Are these the constrained max proportions for each image?

Or are these the breakpoints at which the images are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width defined in `data-srcset` is the decoded width of the image.

Breakpoints can be defined and mapped to individual image widths using the `data-sizes` property if you wish to have more control over using `auto`

Source: lazysizes repo links to [this blog post](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/anatomy-of-responsive-images/) explaining the syntax of a responsive image